# Getting a 'settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value' error

Tags: django, database, azure, django-settings

I am using Django to connect to an on-premise database. Earlier, the database was hosted on Azure.
The connection string I used within Django settings earlier was as follows-

## for sql database of Azure

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
      'NAME': 'DatabaseName', #notrealname
      'USER': 'username',
       'PASSWORD': 'password',
       'HOST': 'sql-django-uat.database.windows.net', #notreal
       'PORT': '1433',
       'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        'MARS_Connection': 'True',
       }
```

After the database migration, this string doesnt work. I keep getting 'Login timeout expired'.

But substituting 'NAME' with "DATABASE' works. Example given below-

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
      'DATABASE': 'DatabaseName', #notrealname
      'USER': 'username',
       'PASSWORD': 'password',
       'HOST': 'on-prem.local',
       'PORT': '1433',
       'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        'MARS_Connection': 'True',
       }
```

My webapp gets to the login page. But after I log in, I get the error- 'ImproperlyConfigured at /login/

settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.'

Can someone tell me how to solve this? I should mention leaving the "NAME" field blank also gives the same error. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Can you try this tutorial: https://medium.com/@royce236/django-and-ms-sql-server-2012-connection-2018-120c54dfc037 ? Maybe it can help you solve the error.

Comment: What's your Django version?

Comment: Version is 1.11. Thanks

Comment: Hi Suprakash Ghosh, If my answer is helpful for you, can you vote up and mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)?. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you get any progress, please let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
      'NAME': 'DatabaseName', #notrealname
      'USER': '<replace with on-premise DB Username>',
       'PASSWORD': '<replace with on-premise DB password>',
       'HOST': '<replace with database URL of on-premise DB URL>',
       'PORT': '1433',
       'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        'MARS_Connection': 'True',
       }
```

Comment: The username and password is the same for on-prem. Like I mentioned in the problem, this connection string does work but gives the error-"Supply the name value". Leaving the "Name" field blank also doesnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`From the Azure SQL database`, the settings.py should be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}

# set this to False if you want to turn off pyodbc's connection pooling
DATABASE_CONNECTION_POOLING = False
```

**USER**: String. Database user name in "user" (on-premise) or "user@server" (Azure SQL Database) format. If not given then MS Integrated Security will be used.

Reference: [django-pyodbc-azure 2.1.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/)

For on-premise SQL server, the database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '(LocalDB)\ProjectLocalDB',
        'PORT': '',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'my_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

Here are two tutorials, I think you can learn from them to check if you have missed something:

1. [How to use Django with SQL Server LocalDB](https://eclipse-online.com/news/using-django-with-sql-server-localdb/): This post has been
   tested with Microsoft SQL Server 2017, Django 1.11.x and 2.x. The
   pyodbc and django-pyodbc-azure packages will be used to connect
   Django to SQL Server. The version of django-pyodbc-azure must match
   your version of Django.
2. [Django and MS SQL Server](https://medium.com/@royce236/django-and-ms-sql-server-2012-connection-2018-120c54dfc037): The new python module/library is the `django-pyodbc-azure` which supports Django
   2.0 and lower versions like Django 1.11.

Hope this helps.